# Angular - short writing of duplicate child component

Tags: angular, dry

I have 2 same pager components within a parent component:

```
<header>
<pager [prev]="prev" [next]="next" [back]="'songs'" [detail]="'song'" [additional]="exit" [header]="'Please choose a song'"
 (changed)="onChangePage($event)"></pager>
</header>

... list of songs, etc.

<footer>
<pager [prev]="prev" [next]="next" [back]="'songs'" [detail]="'song'" [additional]="exit" [header]="'Please choose a song'"
 (changed)="onChangePage($event)"></pager>
</footer>
```

So I basically display the same component twice, in header and footer.

Is there a way to DRY?

Can I somewhere store all the property bindings, events etc that I will use in all pager components on that view, so I don't have to repeat everything twice (or more if I use it several times on the same page)?

Have in mind its dynamical nature, so in the other view I will use other bindings - e.g [back]="'newsList'" [detail]="'news'" so I can't store that data in the pager component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use ng-template and ng-container like so :

```
<ng-template #dryPager>
  <pager [prev]="prev" [next]="next" [back]="'songs'" [detail]="'song'" 
    [additional]="exit" [header]="'Please choose a song'"
    (changed)="onChangePage($event)"></pager>
</ng-template>

<header>
  <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="dryPager"></ng-container>
</header>

<footer>
  <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="dryPager"></ng-container>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the driest way is to use `ng-template, this could be an implemention:

```js
<ng-template #pagerTemplate>
    <pager></pager>
</ng-template>
```

And then you can use it wherever you want in your template:

```js
<ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="pagerTemplate"></ng-container>
```